# Aligning <a> to the bottom, while centering them?

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

I've centered my nav menu by using the text-align element. I've also aligned it to the bottom of the parent div by using the position and bottom element, but when I use the position and bottom element, it cancels out the text align. Why does it do that? http://jsfiddle.net/CQTEY/

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
    <img src="/images/logo.png" width="96" height="82">
    </div>    
    <div id="nav">
    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
    position:relative;
    background-color: #2C2E31;
    border-bottom: #242426 2px solid;
    height: 182px;
    position:relative;
}
#nav {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    text-align:center; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:raleway-regular; 
}
#nav a {
    border-bottom:#FFFFFF 2px solid; 
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none; 
    margin-left: 8px; 
    margin-right:8px;
}
```

Comment: See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CQTEY/4/ you need to make the position absolute 100% width

Comment: Do you mean you would like to have the Nav menu center-aligned? Remember the `text-align` property applies to the contained elements, not to the container..

Answer (score 5):

The `text-align` property is not cancelled, but when you're positioning your `div#nav` to the bottom, it doesn't use the whole width of `div.header` anymore and is aligned to the left.

In order to achieve the effect you need, just modify the CSS for `#nav` by adding `left` and `right` properties to extend the div to the whole available width:

```
#nav {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align:center; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:raleway-regular; 
}
```

Comment: Or alternatively it's enough `width: 100%`. +1

Comment: This, or the PartyPete comment to the question.. +1 :)

Comment: Ah, I did not know you had to define the width after that. Thanks anyways. Will set yours as answer as soon as it will let me.

Comment: Unless you specify a width (or position offsets left & right), absolutely positioned elements will compute a shrink-to-fit width (floated elements do the same).  Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width